# Elastic search remove multiple types in one index

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, alpakka

One of our application was designed such a way that we have 7 indices each per day (7 days worth), and each indices has mapping has mutliple type say userId, but the fields are all the same per type. It was designed long back (ES2.x) version. 
Initially the userId were just 2/3 so we never had a issue. But recently the application has been opened up for mutliple user ID (in thousands) and we have to remove multiple types(also will be moving to ES 6.x soon)

Can anyone please suggest what is the best way to go about it?
We cannot have multiple indices based on userID (then we will end up with thousands of indices).
Is there a way we can design our index such that filtering based on usedId is simple?

Comment: -nocturnal Can you provide a sample document. Also,maintaining index per userId is not a good idea, it should be part of a document.

Comment: Indeed, `userId` should simply be a field. Then you can have a [filtered alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#filtered) per userId and you query the alias. As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50549252/4604579) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30499551/4604579)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. did some research and this your solution was what i was leaning against. trying it out now.